# Can't open external files in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I want to open a `.npy` file in C++ using the NDK in Android Studio. The external storage directory is at `/storage/emulated/0/`, so I used the following C++ code to open the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_demo_MainActivity_getInt( JNIEnv* env, jobject /* this */) {
    std::string fname = "/storage/emulated/0/data.npy";
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname.c_str(), "rb");
    if(!fp) throw std::runtime_error("npy_load: Unable to open file "+fname);
    return 0;
}
```

I specified the following permissions for external storage access in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <!-- more stuff -->
</manifest>
```

However, Im not able to properly read the file:

`terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: npy_load: Unable to open file /storage/emulated/0/data.npy`

I could not figure out why this error keeps occurring, since I have read/write access to the directory.

Comment: See [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) _"...If your app is a file manager and needs broad access to external storage files, then the system must place your app on an allowlist..."_

Comment: The permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are deprecated and on newest Android versions they don't have any effect at all because shared storage access is now via Scoped Storage Java API.

Comment: That file apparently is not created by your app. Who put it there? Hence no access in this way.

Comment: @Robert. Not true. Every app on an Android 13 device can create files in all public directories in external storage without that WRITE permission.

Comment: @blackapps But in this case terdev had tried to create files in the root directory, nut in a public directory. If you know an overarching answer that explains everything regarding Scoped Storage feel free to link it or write such an answer. There are so many questions because of Scoped Storage changes that it would be very good to have such an answer that explains everything instead of explaining on every new answer the relevant parts again.

Comment: `in this case terdev had tried to create files in the root directory` Yes, and that does not go. And it will go in all public dirs of root directory. All has nothing to do with scoped storage. Its only confusing for OP that you started talking about it. @Robert

Answer (score 0):

Android is becoming more and more restrictive on usage of arbitrary paths, so it may be that you can't access some locations (reading or writing) and there is no way to alter that with any android permissions.
Depending on your usage, if you can choose, use one of the folders that are available to your app.
For example, from java/kotlin you could retrieve the value of

```kotlin
getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath?.let { configDirPath(it) }
```

and pass it to the native with something like:

```kotlin
private external fun configDirPath(path: String)
```

Don't forget to make the directories if they are not there already.

```kotlin
val extDir = File(getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.absolutePath, "")
if (!extDir.exists()) extDir.mkdirs()
```

This path doesn't require permissions for reading or writing, it's public and you can drop files there with adb push if needed.